# Understanding Shao’s proof of Neyman-Pearson lemma

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation

Reading the proof of Neyman-Pearson’s lemma on Shao’s *Mathematical Statistics*, I’m stuck at the very beginning. Here is the relevant bit from the book for convenience:

[image]

How can we conclude that $\gamma(0)=1$? If $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ had different supports, wouldn’t $\gamma(0)$ be less than $1$ in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not problem with dividing by $f_0$ since integration is over $\mathbb{P}_0$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_0[f_1(X)>t f_0(X)]&=\int_X\mathbb{1}_{\{f_1>t f_0\}}(x)\,f_0(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{\{f_0>0\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{f_1>t f_0\}}(x)\,f_0(x)\,dx\\
&= \int_{\{f_0>0\}}\mathbb{1}_{\big\{\tfrac{f_1}{f_0}>t\big\}}(x)\,f_0(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

That means that with respect to $\mathbb{P}_0$, the random variable $Y=\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}$ is finite $\mathbb{P}_0$-a.e. and so, $\gamma(t)=\mathbb{P}_0[f_1(X)>t f_0(X)]$, or rather $1-\gamma(t)$, is the distribution function of the random variable $Y$ under $\mathbb{P}_0$; hence,

1. $\gamma$ is monotone non increasing,
2. $\gamma$ is right continuous with left limits
3. $\gamma(t)=1$  for all $t<0$ for $f_1\geq0$ everywhere, and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\gamma(t)=0$.

As for the last question,  $\gamma(0)=1$ iff $\mathbb{P}_0[f_1(X)>0]=1$ or equivalently, $\gamma(0)<1$ iff $\mathbb{P}_0[f_1(X)=0]>0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. I follow your argument just fine, but I’m still troubled about the conclusion that $\mathbb{P}_{0}[f_{1}(X)>0]=1$. Doesn’t this mean that essentially (i.e. with the possible exception of a $\mathbb{P}_{0}-$null set) $f_{1}>0$ whenever $f_{0}>0$? I don’t see why that should be the case when I could choose $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ with overlapping but substantially different supports.

Comment: @Federico: It is not my conclusion that $\mathbb{P}_o[f_1(X)>0]=1$. It could actually be the case that $\mathbb{P}_1[f_1(X)=0]>0$, which means that $\gamma$ has a discontinuity at $t=0$ of size $\gamma(0-)-\gamma(0+)=1-\gamma(0)=\mathbb{P}_0[f(X_1)=0]$. What it is true however is that $\mathbb{P}_0[f_1(X)\geq0]=1$, since $f_1$ is a density function.

Comment: @Federico: consider the example $\mu_0(dx)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x)\,dx$ and $\mu_1(dx)=\mathbb{1}_{(\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon]}(x)\,dx$ for $0<\varepsilon<1$. Try to estimate $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes perfect sense to me. My problem was that the proof states that $\gamma(0)=1$. So you agree that that need not be the case.

Comment: @Federico: That is a typo,  I have the second edition of the book and that has been corrected. It read $\gamma(-\infty)=1$ instead of $\gamma(0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I’m upvoting and accepting your answer, you’ve been very helpful.